# Autofixture initialising List with values

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
using Ploeh.AutoFixture;
using Ploeh.AutoFixture.AutoMoq;

    namespace MyNamespace.TestFixtures
    {
        [TestFixture]
        public class Tests
        {      
            [OneTimeSetUp]
            public void OneTimeSetUp()
            {

                var Fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
                List<Product> products;
                products = Fixture.Create<List<Product>>();
                Console.WriteLine("Got here");
           }
        }
    }
```

Why are there three products (all null) in the List.  Surely there should be none (0)?

**Update**

Following on from an answer below.  Say I wanted to do create a list with Autofixture:

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
var Product1 = new Product() { id=1, description='Product1' };
var Product2 = new Product() { id=2, description='Product2' };
products.add(Product1);
products.Add(Product2);
```

How would I do it?

Comment: Why use autofixture at all if you're creating your mock data manually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default count for lists is 3, this change be changed with the following

```
fixture.RepeatCount = 10;
var list = fixture.Create<List<MyClass>>();

// 10
list.Count
```

Comment: What is the point of RepeatCount? If I create a List e.g. List<Product> products=new List<Product>(); then I expect it to be empty? Don't you?

Comment: For reference to RepeatCount: +1.

Comment: @w0051977 AutoFixture is for creating mock data, in most cases I find having the list full of random data useful.